# Source maps, error reporting and production builds

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, sentry, source-maps

What's the best way to generate source maps for error reporting tools but still not expose them publicly in the production build?

I know that source maps expose your source code, so I want to avoid making them public.

My approach so far has been to generate source maps using the following configuration at `nuxt.config.js`

```js
  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
    extend(config, { isClient }) {
      // Extend only webpack config for client-bundle
      if (isClient) {
        config.devtool = isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      }
    },
  },
```

which works great at generating the source maps I need and with the error tool.

The problem comes when I deploy those files to a static CDN like S3, I

```sh
aws s3 cp ./dist "s3://$DOMAIN" --recursive --no-progress --exclude '*.js.map'
```

then I get errors like the following about not finding those maps.

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/_nuxt/c079cc9.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/_nuxt/5823d8f.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/_nuxt/92bfe22.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/_nuxt/82d7903.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/_nuxt/348e9ee.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

So ideally I would like to generate those maps but avoid those calls when it's deployed in production.

Comment: Because you are excluding them by using `--exclude '*.js.map'` on the `aws s3 cp` command? Remove the excluding from the `aws s3 cp` command and they'll then be uploaded to be found. They're currently being excluded.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with S3 and is a pure Javascript frontend question - I’d advise to adjust the tags and title